# Paging3: "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type" when using PagingSource as return type in Room DAO

Tags: android, android-room, rx-java2, android-paging, android-paging-library

I was trying to imitate Google's codelab for the new Paging 3 library, and I encountered the following error when I tried to have a Room DAO method return a `PagingSource`:

```
D:\Programming\Android\something\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\someapp\something\data\db\UsersDao.java:38: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.paging.PagingSource<java.lang.Integer,com.someapp.something.data.db.GithubUser>).
    public abstract androidx.paging.PagingSource<java.lang.Integer, com.someapp.something.data.db.GithubUser> getUserByUserName(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    
^D:\Programming\Android\something\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\someapp\something\data\db\UsersDao.java:43: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.paging.PagingSource<java.lang.Integer,com.someapp.something.data.db.GithubUser>).
public abstract androidx.paging.PagingSource<java.lang.Integer, com.someapp.something.data.db.GithubUser> getUserByNote(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Here is my `UsersDao.kt`:

```
@Dao
interface UsersDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(user: GithubUser): Completable

    @Insert
    fun insert(userList: List<GithubUser>): Completable

    @Query("DELETE FROM userDb")
    fun clearDb(): Completable

    @Query("SELECT * FROM userDb")
    fun getAllUsers(): Single<List<GithubUser>>

    @Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM userDb WHERE username LIKE :userName)")
    fun checkIfUserExists(userName: String): Boolean

    @Query("SELECT note FROM userDb WHERE username LIKE :userName")
    fun getNoteByUserName(userName: String): Single<String>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM userDb WHERE username LIKE :userName")
    fun getUserByUserName(userName: String): PagingSource<Int, GithubUser>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM userDb WHERE note LIKE :note")
    fun getUserByNote(note: String): PagingSource<Int, GithubUser>

}
```

My `GithubUser.kt` looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "userDb", indices = arrayOf(Index(value = ["username"],  unique = true)))
class GithubUser (
    var username: String,
    var note: String,
    var url: String,
    var avatarUrl: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var uid = 0
}
```

In the [code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-paging/blob/step13-19_network_and_database/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelabs/paging/db/RepoDao.kt) for the Paging Codelab, the DAO method just returns a `PagingSource` with no extra annotations/magic options in Gradle or whatever. I also looked at other examples from Github like [this](https://github.com/ThomasWilliamMarsh/Gif-Finder-Android/blob/0f634daa16abbc89ba6666238bcdeed34c23333b/core/src/main/java/info/tommarsh/giffinder/core/gifs/repository/datasource/local/GifsDao.kt) and [this](https://github.com/chaytanyasinha/Brewery-Database-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kevalpatel2106/brew/repo/db/BreweryDao.kt) that use the Paging 3 library, they just return `PagingSource` with no problems at all. Can anyone tell me if I missed something?

**NOTE**: Before the error itself, I always get a warning about `ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1`, but this warning itself has not caused any problems in the past, but I am noting it here just in case.

**EDIT**: I use the following Room/Paging lib versions:

```
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.5'

    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-rxjava2:3.0.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: I'm getting the same failure. What are your dependencies?

Comment: @RezaBigdeli just added dependencies in the main post.

Comment: in my case:
update version room_version to the latest version.

Add dependency:
// optional - Paging 3 Integration 
implementation "androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version"

Note: Don't declare fun which returns ```PagingSource``` as ```suspend function```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It turns out that you need to increase the Room version to `2.3.0-alpha02` or above:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0-alpha02"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0-alpha02"
```

Comment: I'll try this out

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I should have been more mindful of the fact that the library is still in alpha, hence the bugs.

Comment: I was using an alpha version for the `rxjava` dependency and the stable version for the other dependencies causing a similar error as described above.

Comment: Seem the problem returns with v.2.5 :(

Comment: For me the issue was using a suspended function instead of a normal function when returning a `PagingSource`.